# Determining Sample Size to Show Increase in Disease Prevalence

Tags: p-value, sample-size, disease

A prof and I are trying to figure out how many samples a study would need to show a certain % increase in disease prevalence, but I'm not sure I'm doing this correctly.

Basically we want to know how many samples would be needed to show, with 90% confidence, a 5% increase in brain tumors due to cell phone usage assuming the prevalence of brain tumors is 1/10,000. He doesn't think an adequate number of samples have been taken in previous studies to give this confidence, but I'm not sure how to calculate the numbers myself.

My thinking right now is that I should calculate two confidence intervals using the equation

CI = p +- z*sqrt(p(1-p)/n)

where z=1.96, p is 1/10,000 in one case and 1.05/10,000 in the other case (5% higher), then find the n necessary such that the two CI don't overlap.

Again, I'm not sure if this is the way I should be approaching the problem and any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: From the top of my head, z=1.96 is for 95% confidence, 1.645 for 90%

Comment: Ah, yes you are right. I was using 95% confidence earlier but forgot to change 1.96 to 1.645 for 90%. Is the approach I'm using correct though?